# Duplicate php artisan schedule:run process in Cpanel (WHM) cronjob

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, laravel-artisan, laravel-10

When placing a cron job php artisan schedule:run from the Laravel framework on a Cpanel-type hosting.
The processes are duplicating endlessly.I'm using Laravel version 10, with php version 8.1

cpanel Process Manager (WHM):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTp5W.png)

My cron job code:

```
cd /home/my-project-path && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I already tried to use this cron job code, but without success:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php81 /home/my-project-path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I noticed that processes are created with two different php, "php" and "php-cgi"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QBkz.png)